# Change style sheet with languageSwitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using a language switcher to change language, with this code I am able to change language via jQuery

Code in index.php

< link class="css_en" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-en.css"/>

Code in LanguageSwitch.js

```
this._langSwitchUI.find('.primary-lang').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    StorageUtil.setLanguage(Languages.PRIMARY);
    _this._closeSelect();
    if (jQuery('.css_en').length) {
        jQuery('.css_en').remove();
        jquery('<link class="css_ar" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-rtl.css">').appendTo('head');
    }
})
this._langSwitchUI.find('.secondary-lang').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    StorageUtil.setLanguage(Languages.SECONDARY);
    _this._closeSelect();
    if (jQuery('.css_ar').length) {
        jQuery('.css_ar').remove();
        jquery('<link class="css_en" rel="stylesheet" href="css/index-en.css">').appendTo('head');
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on which part is giving you trouble?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.